# Address missing in csv file when extracting from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, csv

I have been generating a report from SQL Server whereby the job will be running the query and send the results in `.csv` format to my e-mail using `msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail`.

In my report my address field alone had been displaying only half in the csv file. However when I click the cell and click enter full address is shown. How to tune this to show complete address?

My query is like:

```
Select 
    ......, '"' + A.ADDRESS + '"' [ADDRESS]
from 
    tblAddressCustomers A  
inner join 
    tblOrderDetail OD on A.Pkey = OD.Order_Address_Pkey
where 
    OD.STATUS = 'APPROVED'
```

Comment: What program are you using to open the csv?

Comment: is it excel? You probably just need to expand the column. If you were to open it in, say, Notepad, does it display the whole address?

Comment: Yes i am using Excel 2013. In notepad the full address is shown. In excel if i click the wrap text option also full address is shown. But is there any way to see full address in the point of opening the csv file using excel?

Comment: No. A CSV file is just the values. There's no formatting information like there would be in an Excel spreadsheet, which might define things like column widths. Excel will just show all columns of a CSV at whatever the default column width in Excel is. You have to double-click the right-hand edge of the column heading and it'll expand to the full width of the widest field in the column. If you were then to do Save As and save it in Excel format, that change would be preserved.

Comment: Cool..Thanks @ADyson